# How to take screenshot using remote android webdriver in real device

Tags: android, webdriver

hi iam using andriod driver to test my product in mobile.i want to
take snapshot of tests running in real device .is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe AndroidDriver extends RemoteWebDriver. RemoteWebDriver does not implement TakeScreenshot interface. Therefore you need to use augmenter like below. I never tried this on Android device but am thinking this should technically work.

```
driver = new AndroidDriver();           
driver = (new Augmenter()).augment(driver);
File temp = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(temp, new File("C:\\my\\picture\\test.png"));
```

**Edit#1**
I checked that AndroidDriver implementes TakeScreenshot interface [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/android/AndroidDriver.html). That means you don't need to augment the driver.

Comment: It works for me. Android 3.2 on real device. What is your OS/device?

Comment: iam using standalone 2.0.0 jar ? and you guys

Comment: I am using 2.1 jar which is now fairly old. There is 2.7 out there.